# how to sort array in a different order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, search

I have an array which looks like this.

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [cartId] => 667
        [isPack] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cartId] => 668
        [isPack] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [cartId] => 672
        [isPack] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [cartId] => 673
        [isPack] => 2
    )

)
```

I want to make an array by isPack element,which should look something like this.

```
Array (

[1] => Array
    (

       [0] => Array
            (
                [cartId] => 667
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [cartId] => 668
            )

    )
  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [cartId] => 672
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [cartId] => 673
            )
    )  
 )
```

Array two will be two array in which isPack will be array key,and other information will belong to its subarray.

How can I do this?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just do `foreach` over your array and fill other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $new=array();
     $arr = array( array('cartId' => 667,'isPack' => 1),array('cartId' => 668,'isPack' => 1),array('cartId' => 672,'isPack' => 2),array('cartId' => 673,'isPack' => 2));
     for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
          $l = $arr[$i]['isPack'];
     $new[$l][]['catid']= $arr[$i]['cartId'];
     }
     print_r($new);
```

and output:-

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [catid] => 667
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [catid] => 668
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [catid] => 672
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [catid] => 673
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$input  = array( /* your data*/ );
$output = array();

foreach ( $input as $data ) {
  $isPack = $data['isPack'];
  $cartId = $data['cartId'];

  if ( !isset($output[$isPack]) ) {
    $output[$isPack] = array();
  }
  $output[$isPack][] = array(
    'cartId' => $cartId
  );
}
```